# C++ makes possible to reassign reference?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base{
    public:
    virtual void f(){
        std::cout << "Base\n";
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Base{
    public:
    void f(){
        std::cout << "Derived1\n";
    }

};

class Derived2 : public Base{
    public:
    void f(){
        std::cout << "Derived2\n";
    }
};




int main() {
    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2 d2;

    Base& ref = d1;
    ref.f();
    ref = d2;
    ref.f();

    return 0;
}
```

It is said that the reference cannot be reassigned. Here, the compiler accept this code and output is not understandable for me.
Output:

> Derived1
>   Derived1

So, what does mean `ref = d2;` in fact?

Comment: `ref = d2` means `d1 = d2`.

Comment: You may want to see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper

Comment: The way to think about this is that assignment, and *any* expression evaluation for that matter, happens on *values*. References are never values; they're only ever the types of variables. The *value* obtained from a reference variable is the object which is being referenced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What `ref = d2` actually did was assign the *value* of `d2` to `d1` - however, it's still `d1` which is referred to by `ref`. Because `d1` is still referred to, invoking `ref.f` still prints `Derived1`.

Suppose you add a data value `v` to your base class - set it to `1` in `d1` and `2` in `d2`. Change your implementations of `f` to print `v`. You get something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base{
    public:
    int v;

    virtual void f(){
        std::cout << "Base : v=" << v << "\n";
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Base{
    public:
    void f(){
        std::cout << "Derived1 : v=" << v << "\n";
    }

};

class Derived2 : public Base{
    public:
    void f(){
        std::cout << "Derived2 : v=" << v << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived1 d1;
    d1.v = 1;
    Derived2 d2;
    d2.v = 2;

    Base& ref = d1;
    ref.f();
    ref = d2;
    ref.f();

    return 0;
}
```

When run this will print:

```
Derived1 : v=1
Derived1 : v=2
```

Hopefully this makes it a bit clearer.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

References can't be reassigned. They work like aliases to variables.

`ref = d2` calls assign operator of `Base` class and copies `Base` part of `Derived2 d2` variable to `Derived1 d1`.